# Random Generator issue ~JAVA

Tags: java, random

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int ELEMENTS = 13;
        //int[] array = new int[ELEMENTS];
        char[] array1 = new char[ELEMENTS];
        printWord(array1);

    }

    public static void printWord(char[] array)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] letters = new int[array.length];
        for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
        {
            letters[index] = random.nextInt(122)+97;
            System.out.println(letters[index]);

        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

My problem occurs within the method printword(). When it assigns a random integer to letters in the for loop the random method adds the 97 to the 122 instead of having a random number between 97-122. 
Question: I've always constructed my random method this way, and now its not working why? Can you help me with an alternative?

Comment: You forgot to subtract 97 from 122?

Comment: Perhaps `letters[index] = random.nextInt( 122 - 97 ) + 97`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate a random number between two given values, use the following technique

```
int lowerBound = 97;
int upperBound = 127;
int randomValueInBound = random.nextInt(upperBound-lowerBound) + lowerBound
```

Also, you have to cast your integers as chars to display the characters but I guess you already know that

```
 System.out.println((char)letters[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have got a little issue with your code this might help you

```
public static void printWord(char[] array)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] letters = new int[array.length];
    for(int index = 0; index < array.length; index++)
    {
        letters[index] = random.nextInt((122+1) - 97) + 97;
        System.out.println((char)letters[index]);

    }
    System.exit(0);
}
```

please [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java) for more information